# Two quadratic equations having a common root

Tags: quadratics

If quadratic equations $a_1x^2 + b_1x + c_1 = 0$ and $a_2x^2 + b_2x + c_2 = 0$ have both their roots common then they satisy,
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2} = \frac{c_1}{c_2}$$

But even if both the quadratic equations have only **one** common root say $\alpha$ then at $x=\alpha$ 
$$a_1\alpha^2 + b_1\alpha + c_1 = 0 \implies \frac{a_1}{c_1}\alpha^2 + \frac{b_1}{c_1}\alpha =-1$$ $$similarly$$ $$a_2\alpha^2 + b_2\alpha + c_2 = 0 \implies \frac{a_2}{c_2}\alpha^2 + \frac{b_2}{c_2}\alpha =-1$$

which on comparing gives me $$\frac{a_1}{c_1} = \frac{a_2}{c_2}, \space \frac{b_1}{c_1} = \frac{b_2}{c_2}  \implies \frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2} = \frac{c_1}{c_2}$$

Where am I going wrong in understanding this?

Comment: You can't equate coefficient with only one root $\alpha$.  For example, you could have $\frac{a_1}{c_1}=\frac{a_2}{c_2}+1$, $\frac{b_1}{c_1}=\frac{b_2}{c_2}-\alpha$.

Comment: Your expression following "which on comparing gives me" is not justified.  Assuming (as you have) that $0 \neq c_1, c_2$, in general the equation $K_1\alpha^2 + L_1\alpha = K_2\alpha^2 + L_2\alpha$ does not imply that $K_1 = K_2$ and $L_1 = L_2$.  Remember, $\alpha$ is a **fixed** value.

Comment: What you get is a sufficient but not necessary condition. For the two pairs of ratios to be equal, you need the identity to hold for two distinct $\alpha$'s.

Comment: @IAmAGuest "What you get is a sufficient but not necessary condition" : did you intend "a necessary but not sufficient condition"?

Comment: @user2661923: I am talking about the OP's condition.

Comment: Try working with these equations which have only one common root. They might provide some insight.

$$(x+1)(x-1)\quad =x^2-1\space\quad =x^2+0x-1 = 0\\
(x-1)(x-1) \quad = (x-1)^2\quad = x^2+2x+1 = 0$$